# I need help in nodejs

Tags: node.js, push

I need help . I don't know why **push** sends an **empty** object to the **users** array  Thanks for your help.

```html
                const users = [];
    
                app.post('/register', urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
                    try {
                      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
                      users.push({
                        id: Date.now().toString(),
                        name: req.body.username,
                        email: req.body.email,
                        password: hashedPassword
                      })
                      res.redirect('/login')
                    } catch {
                      res.redirect('/register')
                    }
                    console.log(users)**
                  })
```

Comment: where are you testing that its empty? after the redirect?

Comment: Are you sure that `try` statement doesn't throws an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the same code and it worked fine for me. Complete code

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    
    var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    const users = [];
    app.post('/register', urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
            users.push({
                id: Date.now().toString(),
                name: req.body.username,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hashedPassword
            })
            res.redirect('/login')
        } catch (e){
            res.redirect('/register')
        }
        console.log(users)
      })
```

Comment: Deepak Joshi , Thank you very much, the problem was with equire ('bcrypt-nodejs'), and
Require ('bcryptjs') helped; :)